# Skype does not start under a standard user after a while with a "You must be an admin" message

Tags: windows-7, skype

There is a Windows 7 laptop which has multiple users. It's typically only used by user A, who is a standard user (non-admin). I (the admin) have installed Skype from skype.com and checked that it runs correctly under both my account and the standard account.

After a few weeks Skype refused to run with a "You must be logged in as an administrator when installing this program." message under the standard user, while still running correctly under admin. I've reinstalled it to become Skype 8.13.0.3 and the issue went away, that was a month ago. A week ago the same issue happened: doesn't run under a standard user, runs under admin, manually updating to Skype 8.15.0.4 helped.

How do I make sure that the user may use Skype for a long time without me intervening every few weeks without giving them admin privileges?

My assumption is that there is some auto-update mechanism which prevents older versions of Skype from running unless they can auto-update.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. It often requires updates that can only be performed by an admin account. However, once opened and updated in that account all the other should be able to use the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a way to temporarily resolve this. It turns out that it is a pending update that causes this, and skype updates upon opening by default now it seems.

So naturally when a standard user opens skype.exe and it tries to update, you get hit with "installation error, you must be logged in as an administrator when installing this program" or something to that effect.

The workaround is, open CMD on the machine and type: 
Runas /user:DOMAIN\ADMINACCOUNT cmd
*enter password for admin account*

In the elevated CMD window that will appear if this is succesful, navigate to the location of skype.exe using cd commands (for me it was C:\Program Files (x86)\ Microsoft\ Skype\ Skype.exe) and run the skype.exe with the elevated permissions.

It should open and update. Once that is done you can close it and close the CMD window and the standard user should now be able to open the application.

be warned that this will likely repeat each time an update is available, so a better solution that isn't making everyone a local admin would be amazing. 
For me, I've just switched everyone from skype to skype for business.